# procedure to return a result from existing query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a stored procedure which when called will return me multiple results

so a small variation in my sql code is:

```
@getnames = select * from mytable order by firstname;
    @getActivename = select * from @getnames where Status = 19;
```

but that sems to be failing and i am not sure what i am doing wrong here

Comment: You need to describe how it is failing, and include the error message in your question

Comment: Stored procedures only return a single value, an integer, which if used at all is usually used to return status information.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want :

```
 select top (1) @getActivename = firstname
 from mytable
 where Status = 19
 order by firstname;
```

According to your code you don't need to use two *variables* you can directly express it as by using single variable.